# NoClassDefFoundError when using the StandOut Library

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to use the [StandOut API](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531) to make a windowed app. When I used the example folder, there came a whole bunch of issues about where it needs to point to and stuff like that. I solved all of it, but it came with a

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

There is no gradle file in the library as many of the other Stack Overflow answers had ways to solve it using gradle. I have made no edits to the library except for stuff like output "questions". You can download the library using [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531) to test it on your computer. I am using Android Studio 1.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update android studio to new version. Sure that Your class have mapping on your project. Try add this code to your application class:

```
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base){
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Hope It help you. good luck

Comment: Could you tell me which application class(by file name i.e. MultiWindow.java)

Comment: create a java class file and extends Application. Then add to manifest.
Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: Thanks - I will try it :)

Comment: It did not seem to work out for me. It did not know what "MultiDex" was.

Comment: so, can you show your logcat error?
Do you add `multiDexEnabled true` to gradle?

Comment: I do not have a gradle file. Is there any other way? I have already tried to use the tools.google.com page for it, but I can't get Gradle into the project.   Btw, I am using Windows, not Linux on Mac OSX. @PhanSinh

Comment: so you use eclipse to create android project?

Comment: I was using Android Studio. I did not create the project, I was just trying out the library using the example file. The file that was  there by default id not have gradle(again, I did not create it myself, it was a import)

Comment: Try create new project in Android studio ?
If use eclipse, add your class(jar) has notfound to project config.

Comment: Right, but I am trying to import the code that is there so that I can use the library. If I create a new Android project, it will not have the same functionality as I intended. May you please give me a suggestion to the error without using build.gradle? Thanks!  @phansinh

Comment: I do not know you're doing something that if created by Android Studio it does not have the same functionality. All the project and lib can using into Android studio. And now Android studio has support for Android developers better than Eclipse. If you use eclipse please show your logcat. I will try help you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could do a video of make a couple screenshots of what I need to do. Thanks! @PhanSinh

Comment: I tried your methods a second time and it worked. Thanks! @PhanSinh